# Перечисление адресов через союз «и»

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли запятая после указания номера дома первого адреса? Например: г. Геленджик, ул. Ленина, д. 38, и ул. Мира, д. 4. Или после 38 запятая не нужна?

Comment: Не нужна запятая перед одиночным союзом И. Адреса как однородные члены.

Answer (score 0):

Это не перечисление адресов через союз «и», не в союзе дело, а в обособлении номера дома (в нашем случае).

На форуме я нашла обсуждение этого вопроса (сама-то всегда обособляю):

[«Здание на Петровке, 38, — это символ порядка».](https://korrektor-ru.livejournal.com/851851.html)

[«На Ленина, 7, вы сразу увидите магазин».](https://korrektor-ru.livejournal.com/851851.html)

Верите нам - ставьте! )))